# Deny user access to all subfolders for users without a link

Tags: .htaccess, configuration, webserver

is there a way to deny user access for all sub folders but also activate it for users who came from my page through a link from my site ? I've already tried `Deny from all` but this block the main page too and disallow access for users from links.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the HTTP referer request header, however, keep in mind that not all browser honor this field and it can also be easily forged to bypass the check.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://example.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.+ - [L,F]
```

where "example.com" is your hostname.

Comment: at the one hand it works but in the other hand all resources can not be loaded because they have no permission :/

EDIT: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)